# Identifying rings intuitively

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that the definition of a ring is $(R,+,x)$ where $R$ is a set with 2 binary operations.

Is the set of integers a ring because it is a set and addition and multiplication are well defined?

What would be an example of something other than a group which is not a ring? and why?

Comment: The set $(\mathbb{N},+,\times)$ is not a ring, and $((\mathbb{N},+)$ is not a group.

Comment: Why is the first one not a ring?

Comment: Because in a ring $(R,+,\times)$ we have by definition that $(R,+)$ is a group.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is (N,x) a group? because it does have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: No, $n>1$ does not have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: ok thanks. I got confuses because I thought zero was a natural number lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positive integers do not form a ring because they do not form a group under $+$ (because additive inverses don't exist). This answers both questions.

Comment: Oh ok, so if we are looking at the set of all integers, then zero is included then it has an additive inverse?

Comment: Zero and the negative numbers, yes.

Comment: Why are the set of integers not a field? is it because e.g -2*1=-1 instead of 1? So it is not a field because the negative numbers multiplied by 1 will give a negative number?

Comment: It is not because, for example, there is no integer $n$ such that $2n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

A ring by definition is a set with two binary operations, i.e. $\langle R, +, \cdot\rangle$, so that: (i) $\langle R, +\rangle$ is an Abelian group and $r(r'+r'') = rr' + rr''$ and $(r'+r'')r = r'r+r''r$ (distributivity).

So, a ring will always have a structure of an Abelian group.  $\mathbb Z$ is a ring, but $\mathbb N$ is not since it is not even an Abelian group with respect to usual addition (no inverses).

Comment: In the definition of a ring, does not (R,x) also have to be an abelian group?

Comment: @user204450 If you mean $(R,\times)$ being an abelian group, then no. It is only a group if it is $\{0\}$. If you require the *nonzero* elements to form an abelian group, then the ring is a *field*. $(R,\times)$ always forms a semigroup (a monoid, if you require identity.) In most places, the definition of a ring does not require this semigroup to be Abelian.